# Dart resolving Prefer using null aware operators error

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i resolve this problem:

> Prefer using null aware operators

on this code?

```
AnimationControllerValue halfBoundValue;
double get halfBound => halfBoundValue != null ? halfBoundValue.percentage : null;
```

documentation:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_null_aware_operators.html

Comment: The documentation you linked to has an example of what triggers the lint and how to fix it.  Is there something in that example that isn't clear and should be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's suggesting that:

```
AnimationControllerValue halfBoundValue;
double get halfBound => halfBoundValue?.percentage;
```

would be more readable and succinct.